# Android service/mechanism to get tasks informations in background

Tags: android, service, handle

Hello and thanks for your time.

I would like to be able to "handle" some informations about tasks user in background automatically.

ex :
-The user download a picture from internet with chrome = My app pop and offers its services (ex : save to a private server or anything else).

Do you see what I'am looking for, a 'handling system' ?
I'am just looking for the best way possible (with less use of the battery).

Thanks in advance :-)

Comment: Any download activity of an app cannot be seen by other apps. So your app cannot know what other apps are downloading.

Comment: Ok thanks for reply, but, apps like dropbox notify you when a new picture is available to upload to their servers. Do you have an idea how they do that ?

Comment: No I don't think so, you see the dropbox option for uploading to their servers when you share the downloaded picture.

Comment: Okay thanks for your help.